# Build not reflecting on itunesconnect.apple.com

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Many time, I have uploaded build from XCode (using appstore distribution profile). Everytime I am getting "Submission successfull" window.
But I am not getting build visible on iTunesconnect.apple.com.
I had waited even for couple of hours.

Please help me out.

Comment: I am having same issue, let me know if you find a solution, i've tried removing/deleting all cookies for itunesconnect but this hasnt solved the issue

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried contacting Apple support but no luck so far. Now I am unable to upload binary also. It stucks at verifying assets.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this issue was on iTunes.
I have just upgraded app version and build version from 2.4.1 to 2.4.2 and successfully submitted build and within few seconds its reflecting on iTunesconnect.